# Using different datasource for Odata

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, datasource, aspnetboilerplate

Does anyone know how I can use Odata and point it to a different datasource? Currently, EF in my host project is pointed to my SQL DB. I would like to have my Odata controller hit a different reporting DB (SQL Server or Mongo).

How would I implement such a design?

Comment: these two links can help you https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-Integration

Comment: show what you've done so far.